# Is there any changes required in the .htaccess file to acces the API routes?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

I have added a few routes to the `api.php` file. These routes are working perfectly in the localhost environment.

```
http://localhost/api/v1/events
```

gives desired output but when uploaded to the production/remote server I cannot access it using the domain name.

```
http://domainname/api/v1/events
```

throws an 404 error. I am using the same `.htaccess` files in the localhost as well as in the prod/remote server. I am not sure why is it not working correctly in the prod/remote server.

By the way, I have web routes which works fine in both the environments. My `.htaccess` file is  copied below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Modified .htaccess as per the answer but it is not working for me :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # API
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api.php/$1 [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Tried this as well.

RewriteRule ^api/(.*) routes/api.php/$1 [L]

Can anyone help by advising what is wrong?
[image]
My root folder

[image]

the folder in which api.php is available

[image: On Local host]

[image: On Remote/Prod server]

Comment: Could you please do confirm once if your `index.php` is present in same folder where your .htaccess file is present?

Comment: yes it is.  @RavinderSingh13

Comment: "I am not sure why is it not working correctly in the prod/remote server." - But there is nothing in the `.htaccess` file you posted that would seemingly make this work on the local server either? So, how is this working on the local server?? With the `.htaccess` file you posted, a request for `/api/v1/events` would be routed through `index.php`, which would not seem to be the intention? I assume you don't have a physical directory called `/api`? You just have a file called `/api.php` and these requests should be passed as path-info?

Comment: I just have a file called api.php no directory @MrWhite

Comment: Can you please mention what are the changes required?

Comment: How are you wanting to pass the URL-path to `api.php`? As path-info? Or simply route the request to `/api.php` and your script parses the URL-path from `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, as path-info.

Comment: If it is working through `index.php`, check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled on server.

Comment: @Tpojka , my web routes are working just fine in the remote browser

Comment: @Tpojka - remote server

Answer (score 2):

The confusing part about this is that you say it works "perfectly in the localhost", yet you are using the same `.htaccess` file in both environments. This cannot work on localhost unless you have some other directives somewhere since there is nothing that would rewrite such a request to `/api.php`.

To enable this, and pass the additional path information as path-info to `api.php`, then you would need to add something like the following after the `# Handle Authorization Header` rule:

```
# API
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api.php/$1 [L]
```

This would internally rewrite a request of the form `/api/v1/events` to `/api.php/v1/events`, allowing `api.php` to read `/v1/events` from the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` superglobal.

Without this directive (and with MultiViews being disabled) a request of the form `/api/v1/events` would be routed through `index.php` instead where I assume the "route" is not defined, hence the 404.

---

**UPDATE#1:** No my `/api.php` is under the same directory which has `web.php`, that is `routes`

In that case, you need to modify the above rule to read:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) routes/api.php/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE#2:** from your updated URL structure, it seems that `/routes` is actually under `/myprojectfolder` in the document root (where the `.htaccess` and `index.php` files are located), so you would need to modify the above to account for this. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) myprojectfolder/routes/api.php/$1 [L]
```

However, it seems that a direct request for `/myprojectfolder/routes/api.php/v1/events` does not work anyway, so passing this as *path-info* would not seem to be the correct course of action to begin with.

Comment: I tried it, but still no luck.  My connection to the remote is not secured. Would that be a problem? I appreciate your efforts @MrWhite

Comment: By "not secured", you mean you don't have a security cert and are using plain HTTP? That would not be a problem here.

Comment: yes, there is no security certificate.  i edited the answer to include the code of my new htaccess. Thanks.@MrWhite

Comment: If you request `/api.php/v1/events` directly (effectively bypassing this rule) does it work?

Comment: No, http://localhost/api.php/v1/events is showing the 404 error

Comment: On localhost do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Perhaps in parent directories? Or any directives in the server config? It is puzzling how this is seemingly working on localhost?

Comment: If `http://localhost/api.php/v1/events` results in a 404 then `/api.php/v1/events` can't be the correct end-point?

Comment: Does `/api.php` exist as a physical file in the document root?

Comment: I tried renaming the .htaccess file and my app stopped working so that is the only .htaccess file. No my /api.php is under the same directory which has web.php, that is 'routes'

Comment: So, it is located at `/routes/api.php`?

Comment: yes, it does exist under that folder www\projectfolder\routes

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. So, if you request `/routes/api.php/v1/events` it presumably works?

Comment: No Luck @MrWhite . What is your opinion about creating a fresh project with web routes? Updated my question to include your new statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228113/discussion-between-logeeks-and-mrwhite).

Answer (score 0):

```
 If you use passport in laravel and not working token then you use .htaccess
```

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```